# Prom QL: how to filter offline service ip

Tags: prometheus, promql

In Grafana, I used function "variables" to label the values of all the IP of monitored service.
The prom ql is:

```
label_values(jvm_memory_bytes_used{exported_job="$application"}, exported_instance)
```

But I found this prom ql will show the service ip which has been already offline.
Someone offer me the suggestion that using `up` metrics. However, I don't have `up` metrics of every monitored service, because I used "pushgateway".
The one solution I figure is to filter `jvm_memory_bytes_used` metrics which value above 0.
The data sample is:

```
jvm_memory_bytes_used{area="heap", exported_instance="172.21.3.163", exported_job="bdw-base-manage", instance="pushgateway", job="pushgateway"}
93680928
jvm_memory_bytes_used{area="heap", exported_instance="172.21.6.19", exported_job="bdw-base-manage", instance="pushgateway", job="pushgateway"}
79475512
jvm_memory_bytes_used{area="nonheap", exported_instance="172.21.3.163", exported_job="bdw-base-manage", instance="pushgateway", job="pushgateway"}
136522680
jvm_memory_bytes_used{area="nonheap", exported_instance="172.21.6.19", exported_job="bdw-base-manage", instance="pushgateway", job="pushgateway"}
```

I revised the prom ql into

```
label_values(jvm_memory_bytes_used{exported_job="$application"} > 0, exported_instance)
```

but it has some syntax mistake.
I hope someone could give the some advice of how to filter offline service ip.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you [shouldn't be using Pushgateway to convert Prometheus to push-based monitoring system](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/).

Exactly the reason of your problem stated [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/):

> - The Pushgateway never forgets series pushed to it and will expose them to Prometheus forever unless those series are manually deleted via the Pushgateway's API.
>
> The latter point is especially relevant when multiple instances of a job differentiate their metrics in the Pushgateway via an `instance` label or similar. Metrics for an instance will then remain in the Pushgateway even if the originating instance is renamed or removed.

Consider scraping metrics using pull model.

The best you can do, if you still insist on using Pushgateway, is to expose one additional metric, something like `mysystem_last_push_timestamp` with the value of UNIX timestamp (in seconds, not milliseconds!).

And later using it to determine if your instance is alive with query like

```
mysystem_last_push_timestamp > time() - 5 * 60
```

or in your exact case

Query: `query_result(mysystem_last_push_timestamp > time() - 5 * 60)`
Regex : `/\bexported_instance="(.+?)"/`

How it looks:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! your advice works on prometheus, but when I applied it on grafana's 'variables' function to define service ip, it occurs some syntax error. Looks it cannot appear '>'. The information is "invalid parameter "match[]": 1:48: parse error: unexpected <op:>>". I am confused...Why?

Comment: @estherlee, sorry my bad, Grafana doesn't accept queries inside of `label_values`. Corrected answer, to use `query_result` and extract `exported_instance` using regex.

Comment: The wanted data has been filter by 'query_result(push_time_seconds{exported_job="push-center"}>0)', but when I change it into 'query_result(push_time_seconds{exported_job="push-center"}>0) | regex /exported_instance="([^"]*)"/' to extract exported_instance some error occurs...Can you help me?

Comment: @estherlee, I obviously don't have your metrics, but I attached screenshot of my configuration with similar query. As you can see it works. How this helps.

Comment: Thank u so much! I know where I made a mistake. It works~